# Override the function of this._secondaryEvents mousedown touchstart to mousedown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I want to override a part in https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js. I want to change mousedown touchstart in the javascript file to mousedown. I can't change in the downloaded bootstrap.datepicker.js file instead I should override it in my javascript file by rewriting it. I don't have an idea on how to change this as it is in an array.

I don't know how to override these type of functions.

```
[$(document), {
  'mousedown touchstart': $.proxy(function(e) {
    // Clicked outside the datepicker, hide it
    if (!(
        this.element.is(e.target) ||
        this.element.find(e.target).length ||
        this.picker.is(e.target) ||
        this.picker.find(e.target).length ||
        this.isInline
      )) {
      this.hide();
    }
  }, this)
}]
```

I want to change in my js file as

```
[$(document), {
  'mousedown': $.proxy(function(e) {
    // Clicked outside the datepicker, hide it
    if (!(
        this.element.is(e.target) ||
        this.element.find(e.target).length ||
        this.picker.is(e.target) ||
        this.picker.find(e.target).length ||
        this.isInline
      )) {
      this.hide();
    }
  }, this)
}]
```